# How to set a header as the "default sort" in React?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, sorttable.js

I'm using Sorttable in my React application to make the headers of my table sortable. It's functioning as expected but I'd like to be able to set the default sort to a specific header.
I've checked the documentation [here](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) and have also attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695675/set-a-default-sort-column-in-sortable) solution from a stack overflow response on a similar question.
I was unable to get the default sort to work. Any advice on how I can accomplish this in React; either using sorttable or otherwise? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the default sort using the .sort() method on my array.

Here is a function to sort the properties. You can change the return order from a to b if you'd like to have ascending vs descending order.

```
  function dynamicSort(property) {
    return function (a, b) {
      return b[property] - a[property];
    };
  }
```

Then use the sort() method to call the function with the name of the property you'd like to sort by.

```
  trucks.sort(dynamicSort("status"));
```